# How to separately validate each simple HTML radio form, created through a PHP loop, using Javascript and Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, html, radio-button

I made a number of html forms containing only radio buttons and a submit button. However, I cannot get them to validate properly--independently of each other. Here is my code:

PHP/HTML code for the form:

```
<table>
<?php
for($i=0; $i<count($array1); $i++)
{
  $number = $i + 1;
  echo "<TR><TD>;
  echo "<form name='move' action='listChange_controller.php' method='POST'>Title:<br/>
        <input type='radio' name='change".$number."' value = 'val1' />Thing1
        <input type='radio' name='change".$number."' value = 'val2'/>Thing2
        <input type='radio' name='change".$number."' value = 'val3'/>Thing3
        <input type='button' name='submit' value='submit' onClick='validate(".$number.");'/>";
  echo "</form>";
  echo "</TD></TR>";
}
?>
</table>
```

Here is the javascript/jquery I have been trying, but has not worked:

```
function validate(number)
{
    var name_var = 'change'+number;
    if($('input:radio[name=name_var]:checked').length > 0)
    {
        $.post('file.php',{ name_var:$('input:radio[name=name_var]:checked').val()});
    }
    else
    {
       alert('You must choose');
       return false; 
    }
}
```

When I do this, it always thinks I have not chosen a radio button before pressing submit; it always carries out the 'else' part of my javascript function.

Please let me know why it is not working, and what would work. Any help and suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This line...

```
if($('input:radio[name=name_var]:checked').length > 0)
```

should read

```
if($('input:radio[name=' + name_var + ']:checked').length > 0)
```

Comment: No Problem. I would add few things also. 1) The correct way to use the radio select is to provide *one option selected by default*. See the following (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3457073/should-one-html-radio-button-in-a-radio-group-always-be-checked). This would negate the need for validation at all. 2) Also it's good practice NOT to bind your functions to events in your markup see (http://api.jquery.com/category/events/). 3) You should use the <label> tag to tie your labels to the radio buttons, that means that your user can click the label instead of the small select element.

Comment: Thank you, the information you have provided is very helpful. :)

Answer (score 2):

Change...

```
if($('input:radio[name=name_var]:checked').length > 0)
```

to...

```
if ($('input[name=' + name_var + ']').is(':checked'))
```

Comment: is there an advantage of that over changing it to if($('input:radio[name=' + name_var + ']:checked').length > 0) instead? Thanks!

Comment: No real advantage, just personal preference. It looks cleaner to me.

Comment: Fair enough. Now I know of multiple ways to write the code. I appreciate it.