# How can I validate that a radio button was selected using cfform built-in validation?

Tags: validation, coldfusion, radio-button, cfform

Say I have a simple cfform that looks like this:

```
<cfform id="fruitForm" method="post" action="">
    <cfinput type="radio" name="fruit" id="fruit_apple" value="Apple" /><label for="fruit_apple">Apple</label><br />
    <cfinput type="radio" name="fruit" id="fruit_orange" value="Orange" /><label for="fruit_orange">Orange</label><br />
    <cfinput type="radio" name="fruit" id="fruit_pear" value="Pear" /><label for="fruit_pear">Pear</label><br />

    <cfinput type="submit" name="submitFruit" id="submitFruit" value="Submit" />
</cfform>
```

How can I use the built-in cfform validation to ensure that at least one radio button in this group is selected? I've tried adding a validate="required" to each of the radio buttons but it doesn't work. Is there any simple way to "require" one of the buttons to be selected using cfform validation?

Comment: Don't ever use CFFORM, and if for some reason you do don't ever use the built in validation, and if for some reason you do, you deserve whatever pain you get from it.

Comment: @ScottStroz - I've heard this before but don't really see why. For a short simple form, that you'd like clear simple validation (I'm talking 1 required field and 1 numeric or something really simple), why can't you use a cfform and skip writing your own js code?

Comment: Because `cfform` is the spawn of Satan and every time someone uses it, a kitten dies. Seriously, though, even for a single field form, I would not use `cfform` or the built in validation and the main reason why is because it would not be in use elsewhere and I think that there should be some consistency in your application. EVERY form should be validated and persisted using the same processes, otherwise, managing the application becomes difficult.

Comment: And, the fact that you had to ask for help about using `cfform` and built-in validation on a form with 3 elements should be reason enough NOT to use `cfform`.....ever.

Comment: IMHO, when you have a set of radio buttons, at least one should be set. That would get around the whole, required radio button issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3457073/should-one-html-radio-button-in-a-radio-group-always-be-checked

Comment: @JamesMohler I agree with you that one should be set, but there would still need to be server side validation that a radio button was checked.

Comment: I disagree with both Scott and James.  To purchase application software and then re-invent some of it's functionality seems silly to me.  Also, stating that having to ask a question about something justifies not using it does not make any sense to me at all.  As far as pre-selecting one of the radio buttons, it has advantages and disadvantages over not doing so.  A lot depends on the situation.

Comment: Just thought I would add a link to Ben Forta's thoughts on NOT using the ColdFusion built-in functions. [When Using ColdFusion (built-in functions) No Longer Makes Sense](http://forta.com/blog/index.cfm/2012/11/25/When-Using-ColdFusion-No-Longer-Makes-Sense)

Comment: @DanBracuk Using `cfform` and and the other half-assed implementations in the ColdFusion UI libraries is a waste of time and effort. First, you WILL have problems, eventually, that will make you wish you had not used them. Second, knowing how to use `cfform` may make you a better ColdFusion developer, but the skill does not transfer to other technologies. Knowing how to use `form` with a JS library WILL transfer to any other language. Lastly, just about anything you can do with `cfform` and the other UI crap can be done easier and faster with other libraries - and they can be updated.

Comment: @froadie You do not need JS to handle form validation - regardless of how big the form is. You need JS to do client side validation, for sure, but you should ALWAYS do server side validation. And, you can do server side validation very easily *without* using `cfform`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do yourself a favor and don't use `cfform` for validation. Write your own server and client side validation, but according to the [cfinput documentation](https://learn.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/cfinput) if you add a `required="true"`  attribute to each radio button ColdFusion will do the client side validation for you.

Note: The user can bypass this validation and still submit a form without checking a radio button. You need to have server side validation as well.

```
<cfform id="fruitForm" method="post" action="">
  <cfinput type="radio" name="fruit" id="fruit_apple" value="Apple" required="true" /><label for="fruit_apple">Apple</label><br />
  <cfinput type="radio" name="fruit" id="fruit_orange" value="Orange" required="true" /><label for="fruit_orange">Orange</label><br />
  <cfinput type="radio" name="fruit" id="fruit_pear" value="Pear" required="true" /><label for="fruit_pear">Pear</label><br />

  <cfinput type="submit" name="submitFruit" id="submitFruit" value="Submit" />
</cfform>
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
<cfform action="abc.cfm" method="post">
<cfinput type="radio" required="yes" message="pick something" name="x" value="1">radio 1
<cfinput type="radio" required="yes" message="pick something" name="x" value="">radio 2
<input type="submit" />
</cfform>
```

In fact, you don't even need the message attribute.  It will still validate.